# Single JSON object to multiple nested Mongoose objects?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## Update 10/20/14

I've shrinked the schemas into one. For me this problem is sort of solved. But perhaps it's something somebody else also would like to know. So, for curiosity's sake feel free to answer anyway!

---

## Original question

I've got a single JSON encoded object that I would like to save to a MongoDB. The object shall be split into multiple documents according to the given `mongoose` schemas.

I guess, some code outweighs a thousand words.

The Mongoose schemas look like this:

```
var TopSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  SubArray: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Sub'
});

var SubSchema = new Schema({
  subtitle: String
  SubSubObject: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'SubSub'
  },
  SubSubArray: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'SubSub'
  }]
});

var SubSubSchema = new Schema({
  somesubsubdata: String
});
```

The JSON object looks like this:

```
var obj = {
  title: 'Dummy',
  SubArray:
  [{ 
    subtitle: 'SubDummy',
    SubSubObject: {
      somesubsubdata: 'Hello World'
    },
    SubSubArray: 
    [{
      somesubsubdata: 'Hello World 2'
    },
    {
      somesubsubdata: 'Hello World 3'
    }]
  }]
}
```

(typed manually, I hope there's no typo...)

So, is it possible to just save this object and have `mongoose` split it to multiple MongoDB documents according to the given Schemas? Well, it should be possible, but is `mongoose` capable of doing this? And if it is, how is it done?

Comment: Do you want mongoose, the node.js module, to do this? Or any code that can split the object and save it into respective mongoose schemas will do?

Comment: I guess any module will do... I'm not necessarily confined to Mongoose.

Comment: Mongoose doesn't do this for you, you need to separately save each document that needs to end up in its own collection.

Comment: Okay... Are there any other tools or modules that might help me splitting the object or do this completely automatically?